# How can I publish to subscriber based on connection id via go library `graph-gophers`

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, graphql

I am using `graph-gophers` library to build graphql application on the server side. I have a lambda works as resolvers and websocket apigateway which works as transport layer. The lambda will take the request from apigateway then call `graph-gophers` library schema methods to trigger resolver. It works well for `query` and `mutation`. But I am not sure how to make it work for `subscription`.

The library `graph-gophers` requires the subscription resolver to return a `go channels` which it listens to. but in case of lambda which is a short lived application, it can't keep alive for a long time. That means I can't use `channel` for publishing data.

What I am doing is to save the socket connection id on a database, when there is a need to publish data, I will grab the connection id from db to find all the subscribers. But I don't know how to trigger the publish in this case. Anyone has any idea about how to do that?